# rails_sql_views prevents migrations on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a rails app that requires multi-table inheritance for which I am using the CITIER gem which itself requires the rails_sql_views gem to produce database views representing objects.

So far, so good. All this works like a charm on my local machine using sqlite3. When I try to deploy the application to Heroku, however, I am neither able to perform a database migration nor able to access the rails console.

The reason seems to be that the rails_sql_views gem tries to access some methods of PostgreSQLAdapter which are claimed to be non-existent. However, when I check the files of the rails repository, I can find these methods in the code. What is going on here?

When I try to run "heroku run rake db:migrate", I'll end up with the following error trace:

```
Running rake db:migrate --trace attached to terminal... up, run.1 rake aborted!
undefined method `tables' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_sql_views-0.8.0/lib/rails_sql_views/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:5:in `included'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_sql_views-0.8.0/lib/rails_sql_views/loader.rb:12:in `include'
[....]
```

Comment: I was able to trace the problem back to the Gemfile by testing the thing locally with PostgreSQL. Replacing "gem 'rails_sql_views'" by "gem 'rails_sql_views', :git => 'git://github.com/mremolt/rails_sql_views'" does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an incompatibility between sqlite3 and postgres adapters with that gem. You should try to keep development as close to production as possible. Try installing postgress locally https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql and see if you get the same error locally. If you do, consider writing a detailed bug report and sending it to the author of the Gem, or attempt to fix it yourself and send a pull request.